# Python failing to encode bad unicode to ascii

Tags: python, unicode

I have some Python code that's receiving a string with bad unicode in it.  When I try to ignore the bad characters, Python still chokes (version 2.6.1).  Here's how to reproduce it:

```
s = 'ad\xc2-ven\xc2-ture'
s.encode('utf8', 'ignore')
```

It throws

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want s.decode('utf8','ignore') instead?

Comment: Yup, you're right.  Whoops :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Converting a string to a unicode instance is `str.decode()` in Python 2.x:

```
 >>> s.decode("ascii", "ignore")
 u'ad-ven-ture'
```

Comment: Note that with the OP's encoding (utf-8) instead of ASCII you'll get `u'adventure'`. I actually prefer `unicode(utf8_string, 'utf-8', 'ignore')` as it's clearer you're creating a unicode string.

Comment: There is also `s.decode('ascii', 'replace')` which can be used to get an idea of the issues.

Answer (score 8):

You are confusing "unicode" and "utf-8". Your string `s` is not unicode; it's a bytestring in a particular encoding (but not UTF-8, more likely iso-8859-1 or such.) Going from a bytestring to `unicode` is done by *decoding* the data, not *encoding*. Going from unicode to bytestring is encoding. Perhaps you meant to make `s` a unicode string:

```
>>> s = u'ad\xc2-ven\xc2-ture'
>>> s.encode('utf8', 'ignore')
'ad\xc3\x82-ven\xc3\x82-ture'
```

Or perhaps you want to treat the bytestring as UTF-8 but ignore invalid sequences, in which case you would *decode* the bytestring with 'ignore' as the error handler:

```
>>> s = 'ad\xc2-ven\xc2-ture'
>>> u = s.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
>>> u
u'adventure'
>>> u.encode('utf-8')
'adventure'
```